# Custom checkout page. Remove shipping method and go directly to payment

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, shipping-methods

I would like to ask if there is a way to remove the shipping method in magento 2. I would like to do is after the cart page, I would go directly to payment method. If the custom does not have a current address saved the text fields will display and if there is a current or default address, the fields will auto populate. Because I think the Shipping method has no sense if there is also text fields for shipping address in the payment method. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If cart contains only virtual or downloadable product, the cart will be marked as virtual cart, you don't need shipping address.

In your case, I think you need the OneStepCheckout. You can google about this keyword. Build your own or buy an extension.

Comment: I have tried the one step checkout but it is too hard to edit the css and html files

Comment: Magento checkout is really hard this is because it’s heavily using JS.

Comment: Yes. Thats why I am having a hard time customizing the checkout page

Comment: But, it is the way you should go :)

Comment: If there is a way to disable the shipping method and retain the payment. That would be easy

Answer (score 0):

You can enable free shipping method to your store. So that customer doesn't need to select the shipping method, it will be auto selected.